# Sonoma mac update causes a warning in my terminal in vs code

Tags: python

This is the warnings im getting.

```
2023-10-06 14:11:24.032 Python[12490:620499] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
2023-10-06 14:11:26.051 Python[12490:620499] WARNING: AVCaptureDeviceTypeExternal is deprecated for Continuity Cameras. Please use AVCaptureDeviceTypeContinuityCamera and add NSCameraUseContinuityCameraDeviceType to your Info.plist.
```

I have a project where it detects the cameras which are connected to my device and in my case I have my webcam frim my mac and it detects also my phone camera from continuity. My code used to work perfectly fine but now (since I've updated my mac) whenever I'm running it its printing this in the terminal. Also the filters that im applying live on the camera live so we can see the changes at that time they just crash my gui and I dont know what to do.

I haven't tried anything yet because I dont know what the warning means and what causes the issue. My code used to run and since I've updated my mac it kinda doesn't like before.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues happening. I don't know which module or system you are using, so I can't help you solve the actual error in the code, but I can tell you how to solve them:

1. You're not coding in a "secure state". This would help you in debugging your code, but it shouldn't affect your actual code. just like the error said, they're just warning you that `NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState` isn't active. if you want it to dissapear, then it's best to just set `applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState` to true.
2. The function/class you used for finding the cameras is now deprecated, and you should move to `AVCaptureDeviceTypeContinuityCamera` instead of `AVCaptureDeviceTypeExternal` and also add `NSCameraUseContinuityCameraDeviceType` into `info.plist`

According to these errors, I'm assuming you updated to version macOS14. I'm hoping those would be the only errors you'll discover, but there would probably be a lot more new features to deal with and a lot of features that are going to get deprecated.

Comment: This makes sense for systems where these variables can be examined and set, but apparently many users are getting the error out of oblique Python packages where there is no obvious indication of where the problem is or how you would manipulate these variables. How _would_ you?

Answer (score 0):

**When Using IPython**

For me not only would I get the warning but when using ipython there was no window showing up. The command just went into the abyss.

I managed to get around this by implementing --matplotlib in ipython. So in your virtual environment, once you have ipython and matplotlib installed, you can initiate in MacOS by

```
ipython --matplotlib
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround: python your_script.py 2>&1 | sed '/Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state!/d'

Comment: It would be better if you explained how your suggestion would exactly solve the problem stated in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is just a stupid workaround to (clumsily) hide the error message.