# Python Terminal Warning with Sonoma 14.0 Mac os

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-sonoma

I hope someone can help, when executing code on Pycharm I get this on the terminal:
NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.

The script runs but clicking on the  app created  seems to go funny  missing clicks and not executing as expected, this is happening since I installed Sonoma 14.0 on my mac.

I found a [partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77244977/843953) about this which is to set to yes: applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState

How can this be set to true/YES

````applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState``` to true